# trunk works tag doesn't? ---ImportError: No module named 2.1.2

Tags: python, django, importerror

Very confused. In my  `workspace`, the `trunk` works fine when I do a:

```
python ./manage.py runserver 9090
```

However when I `tag` it @ `2.1.2` and then check it out clean from the repository to a temporary directory on my desktop.. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 33, in 
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 360, in execute_manager
    setup_environ(settings_mod)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 343, in setup_environ
    project_module = import_module(project_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 2.1.2
```

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django does **not** like it when the project directory contains periods. Rename it before running the project.